# devise not sending recover password email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

the mail configuration is through smtp.

- everything is working ok with localhost in dev mode, devise sends recover password email using smtp conf in development.rb
- manual mail sending with action mail is also ok

when in production mode,

only the host is modified to match the host in production machine

the smtp conf is unchanged, and manually sending mail is ok in a rails console

**BUT devise does not send recover password mail**

how to debug that ?

is Devise really taking  on the global mail conf in production.rb ?
there is no Devise::Mailer override.
and this is uncommented in initializer

Comment: How are you sending mails? Check its logs. It will give you a clue to what might be happening. That way it is easy to find a fix.

Comment: and it does not send the recover password only in Production? are you sure or you did not test correctly production

Answer (score 0):

please share the github page of your project, so we can have a look. Then also share the log of your production server. you can recover it with `heroku logs`. I did configure this for my apps, eventually it broke down. It is a little bit tricky. I did follow some guide. If you did the same quote the guide you followed. I followed this guide, I remember that I had to allow in my gmail account setting the usage of gmail account from my app. Then there is some settings that you need to do in `production.rb`, I am quoting the [guide](https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password/), go to that link to see the full guide and check also other guides online:

> ## Setting Up Production Environment
>
> Now you will need to edit the file “config/environments/production.rb”. We will be adding very similar things to this file. First you can add:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yoursite.herokuapp.com' }
```

> NOTE: You may also need to add this line. When I was setting up the mailer, I did not find this line in any other tutorials. I had the development mailer working, however I could not get heroku to work. I received this error in the heroku logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

> I found the answer here: ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to on stackoverflow. If you come across this, then add:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'yoursite.herokuapp.com'
```

> to your production.rb file.
>
> Next you will have to add in these lines. Once again make sure that you leave the variables as they are.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

read the comments from this post and all the other relevant guides to configure this, you may need to use some `smtp` api to send the email....